# Order SELECT statement based on existence of rows in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SELECT which works as shown below:

```
SELECT [AT].[Id], [AT].[Name] 
FROM [AT] 
WHERE [AT].[C] =@C 
ORDER BY [AT].[BOOST] DESC
```

[AT] is a table.
[Boost] is a computed boolean, so when Boost is true those items will appear at the top of the list. So far so easy. This all works.

Now here is the tricky bit, that some hopefully genius out there can solve.
I want [AT].[BOOST] to be replaced by true/false if another SELECT returns 1 or more records from another table say BT. So, if nothing is selected it is false and if anything is selected it is true.
The SELECT in question is:

```
Select [BT].[Id] 
From [BT] 
WHERE (DateTime.Now >= [BT].[SDate] 
 AND DateTime.Now <= [BT].[EDate]) 
 AND [BT].[SomeColumn] IS NOT NULL 
 AND [BT].[PVId]=[AT].[Id]
```

[BT] is another table.

This would enable me to get rid of [Boost] which is redundant and must be updated daily.

Table [AT] would be:

```
[AT].Id  [AT].Name

1        Angela

2        Kate

3        Caroline

4        Mary
```

Table [BT] would be:

```
[BT].Id  [BT].PVId [BT].SDate [BT].EDate [BT].SomeColumn

1        2         01/01/2012 01/02/2012 not Null

2        3         01/11/2016 31/12/2016 not Null

3        4         01/11/2016 31/12/2016 Null 


4        3         01/10/2016 08/10/2016 not Null
```

DateTime.Now is 29/11/2016 00:00:00

Output would be:

```
3        Caroline  
1        Angela  
2        Kate  
4        Mary
```

So all would be selected but Caroline would go to the top because the datetime now is between the SDate and EDate and SomeColumn is not null. All the others would just come out in I assume their index order. Basically only Caroline would get a boost and would only appear once.

Comment: Elaborate your question with sample data and expected result.

Comment: Good idea. I'll do this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join to inspect the desired BT values, and then order based on their existence:

```
SELECT [AT].[Id], [AT].[Name] 
LEFT JOIN [BT] ON 
  [BT].[PVId]=[AT].[Id]
  AND (
    DateTime.Now >= [BT].[SDate] 
    AND DateTime.Now <= [BT].[EDate]
  ) 
  AND [BT].[SomeColumn] IS NOT NULL 
FROM [AT] 
WHERE [AT].[C] = @C 
ORDER BY (
  CASE WHEN [BT].[PVId] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
)
```

The ORDER BY clause uses a replacement value for BT.PVId because your original case (Boost) is a bit value, so the query wasn't sorting by BT.PVId. If that's acceptable - providing that the nonexistent values remain at the end of the result set - then you can use this ORDER BY instead:

```
ORDER BY [BT].[PVId] DESC
```

This has to be DESC because SQL Server's ORDER BY puts null values first in the list.

You'll want an index on BT.PVId if you don't have one already.

Comment: OK I didn't make my question very clear for which I apologise. I have put and example of tables and output required. I think in essence that your clever bit in the select needs to move to the order. Essentially everything is selected. It is the order that is changing due to values in the second table and the current date.

Comment: @MarkVF Did you try running a query like what I suggested? Did it work, and if not, what went wrong? Your example data is helpful but doesn't indicate to me that I should change my answer.

Comment: it didn't select anything but I'll have another look

Comment: I had a syntax error near Left Join I will investigate.

Comment: OK the syntax error by LEFT JOIN disappeared when I moved the FROM [AT] to follow on - see below. It now selects everything but the boost isn't being applied. I'll investigate this. Let me know if I should have moved the FROM.
  
SELECT [AT].[Id] [AT].[Name] FROM [AT]

Comment: I've added an additional line to my sample data in [BT]. However many records there are in [BT]. There should be no duplicates.  
Moving the case statement to order did give a boost but it also produced duplicates. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use SELECT DISTINCT if you want to remove duplicates.

Comment: I did try that and it threw an error saying something like ORDER must have items.

Answer (score -1):

If it's Sql Server then u can generate sql syntax as nvarchar and execute it with sp_executesql.
First you have to check if query returns results :

```
declare @order_column as nvarchar(100)
declare @statement as nvarchar(100)

set @order_column='default_order_value'
if exists
    (
    Select [BT].[Id] 
    From [BT] 
    WHERE (DateTime.Now >= [BT].[SDate] 
     AND DateTime.Now <= [[BT].[EDate]) 
     AND [BT].[SomeColumn] IS NOT NULL 
     AND [BT.PVId]=[AT].[Id]
     )
    set @order_column='some_val'

set @statement=
    'SELECT [AT].[Id] [AT].[Name] 
    FROM [AT] 
    WHERE [AT].[C] =@C 
    ORDER BY '+@order_column+' DESC'
Execute sp_executesql @statement;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll have a little think about this idea. Its actually meant to happening in the vb code behind. eg

Comment: objDataAdapterC.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT [CHabitats].[HabitatId], [Habitat].[HabitatBrief] FROM [CHabitats] INNER JOIN [Habitat] ON [CHabitats].HabitatId=[Habitat].Id WHERE ([CId] = @CId) ORDER BY [CHabitats].[SortOrder], [Habitat].[HabitatBrief]"